# Discord bot c# get userinfo (without parameter)and send back message

Tags: c#, bots, discord, userinfo

Hi I'm doing a Discord bot in c# and I'm trying to get the userinfo (preferably username) of the person who uses the command
so ex:
user types in command- ?response
(username is hammerhead)
bot reads username and outputs : "HammerHead" in a message along with other stuff

do I use a parameter or can that be avoided I basically don't want the user to type in their name I want the bot to do that automatically.

```
    [Command("response")]
  
    public async Task Response(CommandContext ctx, string first, String last, string email, string 
    affiliation)
    {

       
       //would something like this work I don't really know
        var username = Context.user;


        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(first + " " + last + " " + email + " " + affiliation+" 
        "+user ).ConfigureAwait(false);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't specify which library you're using I'll just tell you for both.

DSharpPlus:

Your `CommandContext` has 2 properties called `User` and `Member`. Both of these is the user who called your command, and as the parameter is named `ctx` you just need to use `ctx.User` or `ctx.Member`. The difference is the user type. User gives you DiscordUser whereas Member gives you DiscordMember.

Docs: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandContext.html

Discord.Net:

DNet CommandContext has a User property as well. It'll give you IUser type. Call it using `ctx.User`.

Docs: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.CommandContext.html#Discord_Commands_CommandContext_User

Tldr;

Either way you have the idea. Just need to put `ctx` not `Context` as `ctx` is the name of your `CommandContext` parameter

Side Note:
You might want to look into using String Interpolation.
MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: oh thank you That helps out so much def best answer is awarded.